# useFormik hook for user authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

Does anyone use **useFormik** hook? I need to validate username and password on the server. For validation I use the handleLogin(username, password) method. Here is my code:

```
const LoginForm = withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues: () => ({username: "", password: ""}),
    handleSubmit: (values, {props, setSubmitting}) => {
        const {handleLogin} = props;
        const {username, password} = values;
        handleLogin(username, password).then(() => { setSubmitting(false); });
  }
})(LoginView);
```

The fact is that if the validation is successful, it redirects me to the main page. This causes a memory leak error.
Here is the text of the error:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    at Formik (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:110048:19)
    at C (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:110430:34)
    at Login (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:13909:71)
    at div
```

Error at the place where **then(() => { setSubmitting(false); });** is called. If you remove it and leave it like that, then everything works fine. But after all, the documentation says that you need to specify **setSubmittingin** the **false** state.

As far as I understand, the error occurs when it is impossible to assign a value. the component will be removed when you navigate to another page. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Where is the shared code using an `useFormik` hook, or *any* React hook? What is `handleLogin(username, password)` doing? If you are navigating away and the component unmounts, there is no component state to update.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked about `useFormik` but only included code referencing a `withFormik` HOC and handling state updates on a potentially unmounted component. I'll answer according to the code included in the question.

By your own admission you use `handleLogin` to validate and submit the form and "that if the validation is successful, it redirects me to the main page."

I understand this to mean that upon successful authentication the user is redirected to another page and the current page with `LoginForm` is unmounted and React is warning you about a potential resource leak with an enqueued state update.

To be clear, this is *just a warning*, you *could* choose to ignore it if you wanted.

I suspect you may only want to clear the `submitting` state in the failure/Promise-rejection path. To do this use the `catch` block of the Promise chain instead.

```
const LoginForm = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({ username: "", password: "" }),
  handleSubmit: (values, { props, setSubmitting }) => {
    const { handleLogin } = props;
    const { username, password } = values;
    handleLogin(username, password)
      .then(response => {
        // log any success message, etc...
        // ...but don't enqueue any state updates
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // log the error, set any error state, etc...
        // clear submitting state
        setSubmitting(false);
      });

  }
})(LoginView);
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. Hope it helps other developers in the future.